# Catch and display error on save_post action

Tags: custom-post-types, filters, hooks, save-post

I wrote this function that adds data to an external db every time a custom post called 'event' is created.  How can I prevent the save from happening if this function returns an error? At the moment, the info is not being added to the external db, and no error is being displayed even though I have a try/catch.

```
 function add_campaign_to_SF( $post_id) {

    if ('event' == $_POST['post-type']) {
        try {

              $sObject = new stdclass();
              $sObject->Name = get_the_title( $post_id );
              $sObject->StartDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST["events_startdate"]));
              $sObject->EndDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST["events_enddate"]));
              $sObject->IsActive = '1';

              $createResponse = $mySforceConnection->create(array($sObject), 'Campaign');

              $ids = array();
                    foreach ($createResponse as $createResult) {
                        print_r($createResult);
                        array_push($ids, $createResult->id);
                    }


                } catch (Exception $e) {
                        echo $mySforceConnection->getLastRequest();
                        echo $e->faultstring;

                    }
    }
  }

 add_action( 'save_post', 'add_campaign_to_SF');
```

Comment: This is not a WP question.

Comment: How is it not a Wordpress question when I'm asking about how to display an error during a wordpress process - creating a custom post?

Comment: Because nothing in your question is specific to WordPress. Your problem is a PHP one. Please see the [FAQ](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: This question is specific to the 'save_post' hook.  Since when I run this outside of Wordpress is works flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress post "saves" work by posting, processing, and redirecting back to the originating page. Put a `die` after your error and you should see your errors when appropriate. Without that, the page redirects before you see the error message.

In my opinion you would be better off turning on [debugging](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) and writing to the [error log](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php).

```
catch (Exception $e) {
    error_log($mySforceConnection->getLastRequest());
    error_log(echo $e->faultstring);
}
```

vancoder is correct that this is mostly a PHP problem, but given that I believe the issue to be related to WordPress' post/process/redirect pattern I thought an answer was in order. If I am right, that should straighten out the confusion.

Also, `save_post` runs after most of the post data has been saved so if you need to interrupt the primary save this is not the hook.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  What would be a better hook to use if I did want to interrupt the save if my function returns an error?

Comment: `admin_init` if you need to interrupt very early, or `wp_insert_post_data` if you want to interrupt after some of the processing is done but not saved. It depends on context.